# Angular : how can set the Directive's priority order?

Tags: angular

How we can set the directive priority in angular4 like priority value settings in angularjs.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular does not have directive priority orders, but with the inclusion of lifecycle hooks, we do need priority orders. Multiple nested *structural* directives (directives that alter templates) are now an antipattern, and attribute directives (directives that alter attributes or properties) are evaluated on value changes and shouldn't need to rely on order of evaluation as they are hierarchical. With the inclusion of `zones`, `Inputs` and `Outputs` should be treated as atomically as possible, with the transformation flow being held in the directive itself and not between multiple directives.

In Angular 2+, it's better to write code that doesn't rely on priority.

However, while it's not part of the Angular API and shouldn't be relied on at all, directives seem to be executed in the order they were declared in the module.